# @Published property not updating view from nested view model - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm unsure why my view isn't getting updated when I have a view model nested inside another. My understanding was that a @Published property in the child view model would trigger a change in the parent viewModel, causing that to push changes to the UI.

This is the child view model:

```
class FilterViewModel : ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name  = ""
    var backgroundColour = ""
    @Published var selected = false

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    
        $selected.map { _ in
            self.selected ? "Orange" : "LightGray"
        }
        .assign(to: \.backgroundColour, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
     }

    func changeSelected() {
    
        self.selected = !self.selected
    }
}
```

The following works as expected, on clicking the button the background colour is changed.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var filterVM = FilterViewModel(name: "A")


    Button(action: { filterVM.changeSelected()}, label: {
        Text(filterVM.name)
            .background(Color(filterVM.backgroundColour))
    })
}
```

However, I want to have an array of filter view models so tried:

```
class FilterListViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var filtersVMS = [FilterViewModel]()

    init(){
        filtersVMS = [
            FilterViewModel(name: "A"),
            FilterViewModel(name: "B"),
            FilterViewModel(name: "C"),
            FilterViewModel(name: "D")
        ]
    }
}
```

However, the following view is not updated when clicking the button

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var filterListVM = FilterListViewModel()

    Button(action: { filterListVM[0].changeSelected()}, label: {
        Text(filterListVM[0].name)
            .background(Color(filterListVM[0].backgroundColour))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternate solution is to use separated view for your sub-model:

```
struct FilterView: View {
    @ObservedObject var filterVM: FilterViewModel

    var body: some View {
      Button(action: { filterVM.changeSelected()}, label: {
        Text(filterVM.name)
            .background(Color(filterVM.backgroundColour))
      })
    }
}
```

so in parent view now we can just use it as

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var filterListVM = FilterListViewModel()

    // ...

    FilterView(filterVM: filterListVM[0])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Do you know why this works rather than referencing the child VM through its parent?

Comment: ObservedObject observes only one level published values changing, in your case reference to child is not changed when internal child properties changed.

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way is to define your `FilterViewModel` as struct. Hence, it is a value type. When a value changes, the struct changes. Then your ListViewModel triggers a change.

```
struct FilterViewModel : Identifiable {

    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name  = ""
    var backgroundColour = ""
    var selected = false

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    
        $selected.map { _ in
            self.selected ? "Orange" : "LightGray"
        }
        .assign(to: \.backgroundColour, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
     }

    mutating func changeSelected() {
    
        self.selected = !self.selected
    }
}
```