# Timer within EnvironmentObject view model not updating the View

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, combine, observableobject, environmentobject

I have a view model, that has multiple child view models. I am fairly new to watchOS, SwiftUI and Combine - taking this opportunity to learn.

I have a watchUI where it has

1. Play Button (View) - `SetTimerPlayPauseButton`
2. Text to show Time (View) - `TimerText`
3. View Model - that has 1 `WatchDayProgramViewModel` - N: `ExerciseTestClass` - N: `SetInformationTestClass`. For each ExerciseSets, there is a `watchTimer & watchTimerSubscription` and I have managed to run the timer to update remaining rest time.
4. ContentView - that has been injected the ViewModel as `EnvironmentObject`

If I tap `SetTimerPlayPauseButton` to start the timer, timer is running, working and changing the remainingRestTime(property within the child view model `SetInformationTestClass`) correctly, **but the updates/changes are not being "published" to the `TimerText` View**.

I have done most, if not all, the recommendation in other SO answers, **I even made all my `WatchDayProgramViewModel` and `ExerciseTestClass`,`SetInformationTestClass` properties `@Published`, but they are still not updating the View**, when the view model properties are updated as shown in the Xcode debugger below.

[image]

Please review my code and give me some advice on how to improve it.

***ContentView***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = 0
    @StateObject var watchDayProgramVM = WatchDayProgramViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            
            SetRestDetailView().id(2)
    
        }
        .environmentObject(watchDayProgramVM)
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .automatic))
        
    }
}

    
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView(watchDayProgramVM: WatchDayProgramViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

***SetRestDetailView***

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct SetRestDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var watchDayProgramVM: WatchDayProgramViewModel
    
    var setCurrentHeartRate: Int = 120
    @State var showingLog = false
    
    
    var body: some View {


                    HStack {
         
                        let elapsedRestTime = watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2].elapsedRestTime
                        let totalRestTime = watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2].totalRestTime
                        
                        TimerText(elapsedRestTime: elapsedRestTime, totalRestTime: totalRestTime, rect: rect)
                            .border(Color.yellow)

                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        SetTimerPlayPauseButton(isSetTimerRunningFlag: false,
                                                playImage: "play.fill",
                                                pauseImage: "pause.fill",
                                                bgColor: Color.clear,
                                                fgColor: Color.white.opacity(0.5),
                                                rect: rect) {
                            
                            print("playtimer button tapped")
                            self.watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2].startTimer()
                            
                            
                            let elapsedRestTime = watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2].elapsedRestTime
                            let totalRestTime = watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2].totalRestTime
                            print("printing elapsedRestTime from SetRestDetailView \(elapsedRestTime)")
                            print("printing elapsedRestTime from SetRestDetailView \(totalRestTime)")
                            
                        }
                            .border(Color.yellow)

                    }

 }

}
```

***TimerText***

```
struct TimerText: View {
    var elapsedRestTime: Int
    var totalRestTime: Int
    var rect: CGRect
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(counterToMinutes())
                .font(.system(size: 100, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                .kerning(0)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.25)
                .padding(-1)
        }
    }
    
    func counterToMinutes() -> String {
        let currentTime = totalRestTime - elapsedRestTime
        let seconds = currentTime % 60
        let minutes = Int(currentTime / 60)
        
        if currentTime > 0 {
            return String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
        }
        
        else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

***ViewModel***

```
import Combine

final class WatchDayProgramViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var exerciseVMList: [ExerciseTestClass] = [
 (static/hard-coded values for testing)
]

class ExerciseTestClass: ObservableObject {
    
    init(exercise: String, sets: [SetInformationTestClass]) {
        
        self.exercise = exercise
        self.sets = sets
        
    }
    
        var exercise: String
        @Published var sets: [SetInformationTestClass]
    
    }

class SetInformationTestClass: ObservableObject {
    
    init(totalRestTime: Int, elapsedRestTime: Int, remainingRestTime: Int, isTimerRunning: Bool) {
        
        self.totalRestTime = totalRestTime
        self.elapsedRestTime = elapsedRestTime
        self.remainingRestTime = remainingRestTime
        self.isTimerRunning = isTimerRunning
        
    }
    
    @Published var totalRestTime: Int
    @Published var elapsedRestTime: Int
    @Published var remainingRestTime: Int
    
    @Published var isTimerRunning = false
    @Published var watchTimer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .default)
    @Published var watchTimerSubscription: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    @Published private var startTime: Date? = nil
    
    
    func startTimer() {
        
        print("startTimer initiated")
        self.watchTimerSubscription?.cancel()
        
        if startTime == nil {
            startTime = Date()
        }
        
        self.isTimerRunning = true
        
        self.watchTimerSubscription = watchTimer
            .autoconnect()
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
                
                guard let self = self, let startTime = self.startTime else { return }
                
                let now = Date()
                let elapsedTime = now.timeIntervalSince(startTime)
                
                self.remainingRestTime = self.totalRestTime - Int(elapsedTime)
                
                self.elapsedRestTime = self.totalRestTime - self.remainingRestTime
                                                    
                guard self.remainingRestTime > 0 else {
                        self.pauseTimer()
                        return
                    }

self.objectWillChange.send()
                
                print("printing elapsedRest Time \(self.elapsedRestTime) sec")
                print("printing remaining Rest time\(self.remainingRestTime)sec ")
                
            })
    }
    
    func pauseTimer() {
        //stop timer and retain elapsed rest time
        
        print("pauseTimer initiated")
        self.watchTimerSubscription?.cancel()
        self.watchTimerSubscription = nil
        self.isTimerRunning = false
        self.startTime = nil
        
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10009

Comment: I have watched that series, any advice on which area I should be looking at?

Comment: All of it but especially the way they handle time. I personally think Timer is a bad idea, especially because it is unreliable. If the user has there arm down for “too long” or they switch to another app to let say play music or send a message your app is put in the background and the timer will fail. I choose to log start and end times instead or let HealthKit handle the time. But that is mostly my opinion a lot of people use Timer, I’ve just never found it reliable enough to log time with it.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comment, I will keep that in mind, I mean, the watchApp was based on the workout app that Apple provided. Still, I want to figure out why my codes are not working, even if I would think about switching to TimelineSchedule and the way Apple did it.

Comment: It is more than likely not working because you are chaining `ObservableObject`s `@Published` will only detect a change when the object is changed as a whole now when variables change. One way to test is to wrap each `SetInformationTestClass` in an `@ObservbleObject` by using a subview that takes the object as a parameter. The other is so subscribe to `SetInformationTestClass` `objectWillChange.send()` using `.sink`. All this will allow you to refresh the view but it is an overcomplicated approach.

Comment: Using the `ObjectWillChange.send()` method is also somehow not working...the view models are being updated in Parent View `SetRestDetailView`, but not in the child View `TimerText`. But thanks for the comment, it must be the view model hierarchy that is affecting the publish method.

Comment: But thanks for your comment, I found SO answer related to nested view model issue and I will try this method - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65269802/published-property-not-updating-view-from-nested-view-model-swiftui

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thanks for the comments, I managed to get the `TimerText` updated, I think I can make things work from here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue with help of @lorem ipsum and his feedback. As per his comment, the problem lied with the fact that

*it is more than likely not working because you are chaining `ObservableObjects` `@Published` will only detect a change when the object is changed as a whole now when variables change. One way to test is to wrap each `SetInformationTestClass` in an `@ObservbleObject` by using a subview that takes the object as a parameter.*

After which, I managed to find similar SO answers on changes in nested view model (esp child), and made the child view model an ObservedObject. The changes in child view model got populated to the view. Please see the changed code below.

***SetRestDetailView***

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct SetRestDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var watchDayProgramVM: WatchDayProgramViewModel
    
    var setCurrentHeartRate: Int = 120
    @State var showingLog = false
    
    
    var body: some View {


                    HStack {
         
                        let elapsedRestTime = watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2].elapsedRestTime
                        let totalRestTime = watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2].totalRestTime
                        
                        let setInformatationVM = self.watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2]
                        
                        TimerText(setInformationVM: setInformatationVM, rect: rect)
                            .border(Color.yellow)

                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        SetTimerPlayPauseButton(isSetTimerRunningFlag: false,
                                                playImage: "play.fill",
                                                pauseImage: "pause.fill",
                                                bgColor: Color.clear,
                                                fgColor: Color.white.opacity(0.5),
                                                rect: rect) {
                            
                            print("playtimer button tapped")
                            self.watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2].startTimer()
                            
                            
                            let elapsedRestTime = watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2].elapsedRestTime
                            let totalRestTime = watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2].totalRestTime
                            print("printing elapsedRestTime from SetRestDetailView \(elapsedRestTime)")
                            print("printing elapsedRestTime from SetRestDetailView \(totalRestTime)")
                            
                        }
                            .border(Color.yellow)

                    }

 }

}
```

***TimerText***

```
struct TimerText: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var setInformationVM: SetInformationTestClass
    
//    @State var elapsedRestTime: Int
//    @State var totalRestTime: Int
    var rect: CGRect
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(counterToMinutes())
                .font(.system(size: 100, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                .kerning(0)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.25)
                .padding(-1)
        }
    }
    
    func counterToMinutes() -> String {
        let currentTime = setInformationVM.totalRestTime - setInformationVM.elapsedRestTime
        let seconds = currentTime % 60
        let minutes = Int(currentTime / 60)
        
        if currentTime > 0 {
            return String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
        }
        
        else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```